# WPF Object based Form Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, entity-framework

I am new to entity framework in desktop app development.
I know that we can bind view by using MVVM and attached it to the POCO, but is there some method of automating the data entry form creating for the entity framework?

For example, maybe I can just add object as data context and it will generate form for me?

I am using VS2013 Express and WPF as the GUI framework.

Answer (score 0):

To generate forms based on your POCO classes, you need to write your own code generator, or use [LightSwitch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/htmlclient), or commercial generators like [IronSpeed](http://www.ironspeed.com/).